# jquery not recognizing $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html and javascript:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="well">
      <form id="registration-form" class="text-center" method="post" role="form">
        <h1>Registro</h1>
        <hr>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="username">Nombre de Usuario</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nombre" name="username"          id="username" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="useremail">Correo</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="correo" name="useremail" id="useremail">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="userpassword">Contraseña</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="contraseña" name="userpassword" id="userpassword">
    </div>
    <hr>
      <button type="submit" name="cmdNewUserRegister" id="cmdNewUserRegister" class="btn btn-success">Registrar</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
var application = {

  init: function(){
    $('#username, #userpassword, #useremail').on('keyup', isEmpty);
    $('#useremail').on('keyup', isEmail);
  },
  isEmpty: function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
      $(this).parent().addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
    } else $(this).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  },
  isEmail: function(){
    var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    if(emailRegex.test($(this).val())){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    } else $(this).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  //se inicializa el objeto: 
  application.init();
  //validación de correo
});
```

Apparently, it isn't working since the classes are not applied. Can anybody spot the problem, here is a pen about it:

[Codepen Sample](http://codepen.io/yisera/pen/hvJHu)

Comment: `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` and `$ is not defined` Solve this errors first.

Comment: Just included jQuery, thanks! Still, the issue persists.

Comment: Did you make sure it's the first script on your page?

Comment: [Please look at this guide for asking questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isEmpty` and `isEmail` are not defined. You'll need to replace them with `application.isEmpty` and `application.isEmail`, respectively.

Comment: Note when in the object context you can use `this` to refer the object `application`

Comment: @RahilWazir that's technically true, but i don't really want to confuse the OP with how `this` works too much. :P

Comment: I don't think so. Go ahead and try to confuse him :D

Comment: Tried this, however it doesn't solve the problem. Is there a possibility that `$(this)` inside each of the methods of the javascript object be referred to something other than the DOM objects?

Comment: @Yisera Try adding a `console.log(this)` at the beginning of the function to see what it is.

Comment: Got it working, thanks! There was a type apart from the this missing on each event handler.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rahil Wazir suggested just add this before isEmpty and isEmail and works:

```
//declaremos una variable que será nuestro objeto y alojará todos los métodos de validación

var application = {
  //Nuestro primer método, el que inicializa todo
  init: function(){
    $('#username, #userpassword, #useremail').on('keyup', this.isEmpty);
    $('#useremail').on('keyup', this.isEmail);
  },
  isEmpty: function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
      $(this).parent().addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
    } else $(this).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error'); 
  },
  isEmail: function(){
    var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    if(emailRegex.test($(this).val())){
      $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    } else $(this).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
  }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  //se inicializa el objeto: 
  application.init();
  //validación de correo
});
```

Tested, note that valid answer given by @Scimonster and @Rahil Wazir first.